# Strip URL's from file using PHP

Tags: php

I have a list of URL's I would like to clean back to their root domain (and sub domains), so far I have this which is fairly simple and works how I need it to:

```
echo parse_url('https://app.ffgx.com/fdgdfg', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
echo parse_url('https://www.fgigo.com/fgdfg', PHP_URL_HOST) . '<br />';
```

However I have a large list of over 200 URL's, so adding each URL like this will be very time consuming.

My question is, how can I upload this script to my server and include an upload button which will allow me to upload a list of URL's in txt or csv format; it will then run through the list and present me with all the stripped URL's?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this with txt file. Where `inputfile.txt` contains your url's that should be 1 in a line.

```
https://app.ffgx.com/fdgdfg
https://www.ffgx.com/fdgdfg
```

Then Store all the extracted domain in array, `$url_list`. Then depend on you what you will do with array data.

```
$url_list = array();
$handle = @fopen("/path/inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
  while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    $url_list[] = parse_url($buffer, PHP_URL_HOST);
  }
  if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I gave this a try and echoed out the array but it's just a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

If your URL's in the file will only be starting with "https" or "http", then you read the text file and by using str_replace(), all the url's can be removed / replaced. And then again you can write the new replaced content into the file.